# Unity 2D collision detection not working

Tags: c#, collision-detection, unity-game-engine

I am spawning children of a parent object and trying to have them kill my player when they collide. I used the function I found on the Unity website but I still cannot get it to work. Any suggestions as to why it won't work?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour{

    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject astroid;
    public int fallBoundary = -10;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "astroid")
        {
            GameObject.Destroy(player);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set the `player` variable in the inspector? is the `asteroid` tag *exactly* the same as in the inspector? Caps lock matters.

Comment: Okay so I just forgot to set the tag. It kills the player now, but it does it when there is an asteroid that is nowhere near the player...

Comment: There's not enough info here for me to know whats wrong with this. Check the colliders of both the player and the asteroid are the right side. Check the scripts are both attatched to the right gameObjects. And `print("hello")` to quickly check what code is being called when.

Comment: Check exact position of player and asteroid colliders. If your gameobject is not visible itself, but contains a visible part, when you move it in scene view, only visible part will move, not root and its colliders.

Answer (score 0):

Set the asteroid box collider as a trigger and use the method OnTriggerEnter2D.